# question about continuous extension

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then I come across the following
definition

$C(\bar{\Omega}) = \{u: \Omega \to \mathbb{R} : u \text{ is uniformly continuous on bounded subsets of } \Omega\}$
in some references

whereas the same notation is used for
$C(\bar{\Omega}) = \{u: \Omega \to \mathbb{R} : u \text{ has a continuous extension on } \Omega \cup \partial \Omega\}$

in other references.

Are they equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

The second set is a subset of the first.

Indeed let $u$ in the second set and assume that $\Omega$ is unbounded.

Let $A \subseteq \Omega$ bounded.

Then  $A \subseteq \bar{A} \subseteq \Omega \cup \partial{\Omega}$ and also by boundness of $A$ the set $\bar{A}$ is compact.

Let $g$ the extension of $u$

So $g|_{\bar{A}}=u$ and since $g$ is continuous on the compact set $\bar{A}$ then it is uniformply continuous on $\bar{A}$ thus on $A$

So $u$ is uniformply continuous on $A$

The case where $\Omega$ is bounded,is easier.